# Android: Handling network connectivity and listview

Tags: android, listview, network-connection

Hi i am not sure about implementing this particular scenario, i need some suggestions on it. i have a listview and i will be updating it by making a server call, if it is a small amount of data it will be quick, what if i have some 5000 records? do i need to load them in the memory or database and then query it and update listview? what is the best practice for this?

Suppose when i am downloading the data and suddenly there is a network drop? then how will i handle the data and updating the listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about 5K records, but ListViews are known to handle well even large number of records
using an effective recycling mechanism. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) for a detailed explanation.

Now, do yourself a favor and use [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) for your network resource loading. It does far better job 
in async loading of records into lists than most of us... In any case either the library you use or your own code must perform the resource loading/networking from a background thread.

You should also apply the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) to your code. Using a ViewHolder
is always a hood idea. it becomes crucial for a really large number of records. Please use it. 

It should look like this

```
class ViewHolder {
    textView text1;
    Button button1;
}

class MyAdapter {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
         if (convertView==null){
              LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
              convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
              viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
              viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
              viewHolder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
              ..........
              convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
         }
         viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
         ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];
         ..........
    }
}
```

And, finally, if you really need partial loading together with a *Load more* functionality, please read:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5000 records you don't should to get all records, you have to limit the query on the server so you do not send all records.

Then you can implement a "Show More or EndLess" to bring more data from the server when needed.

[Example load more](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

Comment: so first i should load them to my database and then update listview?

Comment: suppose if i updated my listview with 20 records and if there is sudden drop in network , how should i handle this scenario?

Comment: And what if i don't want to use any load more buttons or pagination, How should i go about this.

Comment: When you activate the "show more" check if there is internet. If there is no internet connection does not ask her to the server. If there is internet connection you ask the server.

Comment: I think if you should implement paging in a scenario that if you have many records your application will be very slow.